# Access SQL by server name in different segment

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have 2 server, that is server A and server B and both are currently using SQL Server 2016.Server A is in 192.168.10.xxx network and I can connect to it via IP address from server B but not via server name because it is in different network.

And server B is in 192.168.2.xxx network and I also can connect to it via IP address from server A but not via server name because it is in different network.

I want to create a peer to peer replication for server A and server B.

But I can't, because to add a new node in the Configure Peer-To-Peer Topology it must specify a server name, not the IP address of the server.

This is the error that I get when specifying the IP address of the server when adding another peer node in configure peer-to-peer topology.

> SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server. Specify the actual server name, ''. (Replication.Utilities)

This is the error that I get when specifying the server name of the server when adding another peer node in configure peer-to-peer topology.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

How do I solve this?

Comment: Try to use the same DNS for both servers or define both of the server names in the hosts files on both servers i.e edit C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC\HOSTS on both servers and add two entries for both machines.

Comment: @AhmedSaeed What should I do and add in the host files on both servers? Sorry I'm new at this.

Comment: This might be helpfull:https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52662/is-replication-possible-on-two-different-domains

Comment: Add two lines, 192.168.10.xx serverAName and on the next line add 192.168.2.xx ServerBName. insure to put the correct IP of both servers on both.